# Не удаётся открыть базу данных "Students", запрашиваемую именем входа. Не удалось выполнить вход

Tags: c#, sql-server

Драсьте господа. Суть проблемы.

Делаю диплом. Мне нужно закинуть прогу с БД на предприятие. Закинули БД на сервер, но выскакивает ошибка.

"Не удаётся открыть базу данных "Students", запрашиваемую именем входа. Не удалось выполнить вход. При входе в систему пользователя "123" (условно) произошла ошибка."

Сначала думал, что проблема в доступе к БД у пользователя 123, хотя в прошлый раз он подключался к БД без проблем.

Сейчас сетую на Microsoft SQL Server 2017 LocalDB (щас объясню: на предприятии делал прогу с sql сервом 17 года. Дома у меня стоял 19 года. Пришлось снести и поставить 17 года, что бы на предприятии работал тоже и теперь выскакивает эта ошибка).

SSMS не использую.
Вот строка подключения

```
public string connеctionString = "Data Source=sqlserver;Initial Catalog=STUDENTS;Integrated Security=True";
```

Заранее благодарю всех, кто поможет!

Comment: `Integrated Security=True`, используется Windows-авторизация и скорее всего учетка от дома и предприятия разные. Попробуй подключиться через встроенную учетную запись SQL, если таковой имеется.

Comment: @Arkee, Видимо в этом и есть проблема, т.к. при сборке приложения на предприятии, все работало.

Я правильно понял, если поставить 'Integrated Security=False', то мне нужно будет ввести в строку подключения данные учётки от sql сервера на предприятии? 
И можно ли как-то избежать этой авторизации? Что б если я собрал проект у себя дома, то не было бы проблем с доступом к БД на предприятии?

Comment: В основном используется либо Windows-авторизация, либо стандартная авторизация через логин/пароль [подробнее](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/security/choose-an-authentication-mode?view=sql-server-2017). Другие типы авторизации через сертификат/ключ на моей практике ни разу использовались. Примеры создания строк подключения можно посмотреть на [connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2017/).

Comment: @Arkee, спасибо вам за помощь. Буду пытаться.